# Printing list item values of a key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict like so:

```
dict = {
    'page 1' : ['word 1', 'word 2'],
    'page 2' : ['word 3', 'word 4']
}
```

I would like to print out each item in page 1 when I'm on page 1 and each item of page 2 when I'm on page 2.

So far I have:

```
for (page, content) in dict.items():
    print(content[0])
```

Which returns:

```
# output    
word 1
word 3

# desired output
word 1
word 2
```

Basically if the selected key is x then I want to print key[x]'s values.  But not key[y]'s values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to iterate over the dictionary. You want to iterate over a list. The list happens to come from a dictionary, but that doesn't affect how you iterate over it:

```
for content in the_list:
    print(content)
```

To get the list out of the dictionary, you look it up by the key:

```
the_list = the_dict[the_key]
```

Combined, in condensed form:

```
for content in the_dict[the_key]:
    print(content)
```

Comment: You're fast!  Thanks, it worked.  I'll accept your answer when the timer expires.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the content instead of printing content[0].

```
d = {
    'page 1' : ['word 1', 'word 2'],
    'page 2' : ['word 3', 'word 4']
}
for (page, content) in d.items():
    for c in content:
        print(c)
```